# Sitecore Razor Intellisense - Preventing publish

Tags: visual-studio, sitecore

I am starting to learn Sitecore development at the moment and after setting up my solution and noticed that Intellisense is not picking up Sitecore related classes.

I have also already added Sitecore.Mvc.dll and Sitecore.Kernel.dll into my references folder.

I tried creating new projects with the same steps for both VS 2015/2017 to no avail.

On publish, these will turn into errors and hence solution will not be published.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a version conflict between `System.Web.Mvc 5.1.0.0` and `System.Web.Mvc 5.2.3.0`. The last one is used in [Sitecore 8.1 and later](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164).

You should either align the version referenced in your code with the required one or configure the [assembly bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Hi, I have actually tried that out already. Still same errors happening. FYI, I am on Sitecore 8 (Update 5).

Comment: Apologies, my Sitecore version was actually 8.2. I found the fix, as posted in my answer above. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The fix apparently was to **upgrade to .NET Framework 4.6**. 
My Sitecore instance was **Sitecore version 8.2**.

My initial .NET framework was 4.5.2 which was actually also compatible with Sitecore 8.2, however I had no idea why it suddenly worked when I upgraded the .NET Framework to 4.6. I re-tried it on 2 projects and had same behavior.

Below is a screenshot from the Sitecore site showing the compatibility of Sitecore 8.2 with ASP.NET framework version.[image]